# Displaying a Custom Avatar in WP Bootstrap Navwalker Menus in Wordpress

Tags: menus, hooks, navigation, avatar

Am creating a WordPress site whereby am enabling users to upload their own custom profile images from a custom form. Once they upload am storing the image URL in a custom database table and the image is then stored inside the WordPress wp-content/uploads folder. This works fine

[image]

Next, am invoking the Hook filter called **get_avatar in my functions.php to fetch the avatarUrl from the custom database table above via the user_id of the logged-in user**. The code below works fine

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'custom_avatar', 10, 6 );
function custom_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt, $args ) {

    // Get the user by ID or by email
    $user = false;
    if ( is_numeric( $id_or_email ) ) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'id' , (int)$id_or_email );
    } 
    elseif ( is_object( $id_or_email ) ) {
        if (!empty( $id_or_email->user_id ) ) {
            $id = (int)$id_or_email->user_id;
            $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );
        }
    } 
    else {
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $id_or_email );    
    }
    if ( $user && is_object( $user ) ) {

        //Queried profile_details table
        global $wpdb; 
        $query_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM profile_details WHERE user_id = $user->ID");
    
        
        $avatar_url = $query_result[0]->avatarUrl;
        
        if ( $avatar_url ) {
        
            // HTML for the avatar <img> tag.  This is WP default.
            $avatar = sprintf(
                "<img alt='%s' src='%s' class='%s' height='%d' width='%d' %s/>",
                esc_attr( $alt ),
                esc_url( $avatar_url ),
                esc_attr( "avatar avatar-" . $size . " photo" ),                
                (int) $args['height'],
                (int) $args['width'],
                $args['extra_attr']
            );
        }
    }

    //print on screen
    ?><pre><?php var_dump( $avatar ); ?></pre><?php

    return $avatar;
}
```

When I invoke the get_avatar method from website header.php, am getting the image displayed as shown below, but I want it displayed in the far-right corner next to the username.
Ideally, it should be **Welcome test [avatar-image-displayed]**

[image]

Below is the Navwalker class am using:

```
<?php
          wp_nav_menu(array(
             'theme_location'  => 'loggedin',
             'container'       => 'nav',
             'container_class' => 'menu-toggle',
             'container_id'    => 'navcol-1',
             'menu_class'      => 'nav__menu',
             'depth'           => 2,
             'echo'            => true,
             'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
             'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
           ));
                                        
     ?>
```

Please assist in **making the avatar displayed dynamically inside the custom navwalker menu class**, try researching this but have not been successful for many hours.

Comment: Ideally, this is a HTML issue. You need to edit the `header.php` and call `get_avatar()` after `wp_nav_menu()`. If you want to add it as the last menu item, you need filter the [`wp_nav_menu_items`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/).

Comment: @Abhik Thanks for assistance,, Please assist with the wp_nav_menu items I will use. Not yet able to figure that out. Much thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying an Uploaded Image as a Custom Avatar in Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/412445/displaying-an-uploaded-image-as-a-custom-avatar-in-wordpress)